# A problem related to relation definition.

Tags: functions, relations

My book says:

> A **relation R** from a non-empty set A to a non-empty set B is a subset
>   of the cartesian product A × B. The subset is derived by describing a
>   relationship between the first element and the second element of the
>   ordered pairs in A × B.

The book says that **relation R** is a subset of A × B. But how could a relation be a set? In number 5 and 10 there is a relation that the later one is divisible by the fist one. **But "division" can't be any "set" or can it be?**

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. The relation can be identified with the set of ordered pairs $(a,b)$ where $a$ divides $b$; for example, the set contains $(5,10)$ but not $(10,5)$

Comment: It is worth pointing out that functions are also sets.  In fact, depending on your construction of set theory, *everything* can be a set including and certainly not limited to: operations such as $+$ and $\times$, numbers such as $1$ and $\pi$, graphs such as $K_4$, and relations such as $<$ and $\mid$ as in your question, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Abstractly, a relation $R$ can be described as a set of ordered pairs that satisfy the relation:

$R=\{(a,b): a\; R\; b\}\subset A\times B$.

For your example -- the relation "divides" -- we have $(5,10)\in R$ but $(10,5)\not\in R$, for instance.

(In this case we could say $A=B=\mathbb N$; $A\times B=\mathbb N^2$.)